# Very coarse mouse control in Synergy

Tags: synergy, mouse-cursor

I have two computers, a Macbook Air (OS X 10.8) and a Desktop running Fedora 17. I am using Synergy to share the Mac's keyboard and mouse between the two. The keyboard works great but for some reason the mouse has very poor control. I can move it around the screen, but I can't hit a target smaller than say 40 pixels with it. This of course makes it rather less useful than it should be.

Any suggestions on how to fine tune this to be more useful?